Extracting substring between optional substrings
I need to extract a substring which is between two other substrings. But I would like to make the border substrings optional - if no substrings found then the whole string should be extracted.
patt = r"(?:bc)?(.*?)(?:ef)?"
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "bcdef")  # d - as expected
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "abcdefg")  # adg - as expected

# I'd like to get `d` only without `a` and `g`

# Trying to remove `a`:
patt = r".*(?:bc)?(.*?)(?:ef)?"
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "bcdef")  # empty !!!
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "abcdef")  # empty !!!

# make non-greedy
patt = r".*?(?:bc)?(.*?)(?:ef)?"  
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "bcdef")  # d - as expected
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "abcdef")  # `ad` instead of `d` - `a` was not captured

# make `a` non-captured
patt = r"(?:.*?)(?:bc)?(.*?)(?:ef)?"
a = re.sub(patt, r"\1", "abcdef")  # ad !!! `a` still not captured

I also tried to use re.search without any success.
How can I extract d only (a substring between optional substrings bc and ef) from abcdefg?
The same pattern should return hij when applied to hij.

See https://regex101.com/r/VYaWoD/1 for why this is happening. The regexp doesn't match a, so it's left alone in the replacement.

@Barmar no I should not. But I think it should be the simpliest way. I can search for the both substrings and extract the inner substring with String methods. But I think there should be some simple way with regexp

Don't use re.sub() if you want to get the matches. Use re.findall().

@Barmar thanks, I was not aware of this site. Will check

@Barmar tried findall() as well. But it gives a lot of matches and I didn't find a way to extract d from there universally

@Barmar  Shouldn't capturing then work?(the last  test of OP)? More like the problem is there are no real anchors..

This has to do with the way re.sub() avoids replacing overlapping matches. The pattern first matches the empty string before a. Then it moves ahead and matches bcdef and replaces that with d. a isn't matched at all, so it's not replaced and left in the result.

There also seems to be some confusion between matching and capturing. Capturing is what happens with ().

The last two patterns are effectively equivalent. It doesn't matter whether you put the first .* inside the non-capture group, either way the pattern matches the same thing.

"if no substrings found then the whole string should be extracted.": why? The way you use it with sub, you would get the same result if you would not have a match at all.

It seems to me that with patt = r".*?bc(.*?)ef.*" you get the results you look for.

@trincot yes, it works. Thanks. So simple

By making the bc and ef patterns optional, you'll get into situations where the one is matched, while the other is not. Yet, you'd need both of them or neither.
The requirement that you need the whole input to match when these delimiters are not present really overcomplicates it. Realise that if there is no match, sub will not alter the input, and so that would actually achieve the desired result. In other words, don't make these delimiter patterns optional -- make them mandatory.
When there is a match, you'll want to replace all of the input with the captured group. This means you should also match what follows ef, so it gets replaced (removed) too.
Bringing all that together, you could use:
patt = r".*?bc(.*?)ef.*"

Be aware that this will only match the first occurrence of the bc...ef pattern. If the input string has more occurrences of those, the sub call will only return the first delimited text.
